# build arrays to show index number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like:

```
var myArray = [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 15, 30];
```

I need to build a new array of arrays from this to show the index number from the original array in the new array. The final result should look like the following:

```
var myNewArray = [
    [1, 12],
    [2, 24],
    [3, 36],
    [4, 48],
    [5, 60], 
    [6, 15],
    [7, 30]
];
```

Comment: What's wrong with looping? Can you show your code so far?

Comment: @elclanrs I am able to iterate over the array, it's building/pushing the new values of multi arrays into one array that i am having trouble with, i'm not sure where to begin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use
[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then generate new array based on value and index of that array.

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/LGjp9/)

```
var myArray = [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 15, 30],
    newArray = myArray.map(function (value, index) {
        return [index + 1, value];
    });
```

*FYI: - JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0*

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray= [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 15, 30], 
myArrayIndexed= myArray.map(function(itm, i){
    return [i+1, itm];
});
myArrayIndexed.join(']\n[');


/* returned value: */ [
    [1, 12],
    [2, 24],
    [3, 36],
    [4, 48],
    [5, 60],
    [6, 15],
    [7, 30]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as that:

```
var myArray = [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 15, 30];
var myNewArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myNewArray.push([i+1,myArray[i]]);//or just i depending on the index you need
}
```

Even a faster way is to cache the length of the array:

```
for (var i = 0, var l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {}
```

To my knowledge and research so far - Javascript's native `for` loop is quicker than array map for iterating through the array. [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a) is an interesting benchmark.

Hope this helps!